# Why innodb use gap locks for a unique index with a unique search condition?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and the following data

```
id|age|value|
--+---+-----+
 1|  1|    1|
 5|  5|    5|
 9|  9|    9|
```

In connection one, run

```
start transaction;
update bar set value = 0 where id = 8;
```

In connection two, run

```
start transaction;
insert into bar(id,age,value) values(7,7,7);
```

Now the insert statement is blocked by gap lock.

```
lock_id    |lock_trx_id|lock_mode|lock_type|lock_table |lock_index|lock_space|lock_page|lock_rec|lock_data|
-----------+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
5218:85:3:4|5218       |X,GAP    |RECORD   |`bar`.`bar`|PRIMARY   |        85|        3|       4|9        |
5217:85:3:4|5217       |X,GAP    |RECORD   |`bar`.`bar`|PRIMARY   |        85|        3|       4|9        |
```

However, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html ,

> UPDATE ... WHERE ... sets an exclusive next-key lock on every record the search encounters. However, only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row

Is index record lock used only when any records found and locked? Otherwise, still require a next key lock?

Answer (score 0):

A guess...  Both of your queries are reaching into the same gap.  InnoDB does not go to the effort to realize that "8" and "7" would not conflict; instead, it simply locks the whole gap.

I see gap locking as covering a lot of esoteric edge cases -- and doing it in a simple way.  This helps with efficiency but at the cost of sometimes locking "too much".

The documentation was probably written 20 years ago (when InnoDB was released) and no one has noticed the error.  I suggest that you submit a documentation error at bugs.mysql.com.  Those who know a lot more than I do will (hopefully) either explain it better or fix the doc.

Comment: I see that it was turned into a "documentation bug".

Comment: I have already created a bug, please follow this link. Thanks. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107958

Comment: hi @Tim, I didnt't understand the mysql team answer, ¿could you please explain me the answer?

Comment: @Daniel - It looks like the bug has been "verified", but new documentation has not yet been written.

Comment: Ok, thanks, just to confirm @Rick James, "unique search condition" refers to the query TRYING to retrieve a SINGLE row at a unique index, right?